# Jquery click on td

Tags: jquery, html

I need to click on td tag

```
<table width="60" height="60" cellpadding="0" 
cellspacing="0" border="0" style="float: left; margin: 1px" 
background="images/data/source_red.gif">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td act1="7" act3="8" store="true" art_id="4949" cnt="1" div_id="AA_4949" 
         onmouseover="artifactAlt(this,event,2)" 
         onmouseout="artifactAlt(this,event,0)" 
         valign="bottom" 
         style="background-image: url(&quot;images/d.gif&quot;); cursor: pointer;">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

How yo find it by jQuery?

Comment: Can you elaborate? poor question

Comment: @Satpal For example in html i have too many other <td>, by jquery i want to find only by unique sign may be 'art_id="4949"'. And click on that td where have art_id="4949".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Attribute Equals Selector [name=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
var td = $('td[art_id="4949"]');
```

*If have `art_id="4949"` in a variable,*

```
var art_id="4949";
var td = $('td[art_id="' + art_id +'"]');
```

Then to click element, you can use `get(index)` to retrieve the underlying DOM element then to trigger native `click()`

```
td.get(0).click();
```

Note: I would recommend to use `data-*` prefixed custom attribute to store arbitrary data with the element.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want to use jQuery to click on the `<td>` element? If so:

Add an id to `<td>`:

```
<td id="clickme" act1="7" act3="8" store="true" art_id="4949" cnt="1" div_id="AA_4949" onmouseover="artifactAlt(this,event,2)" onmouseout="artifactAlt(this,event,0)"  valign="bottom" style="background-image: url(&quot;images/d.gif&quot;); cursor: pointer;">&nbsp;</td>
```

Then use this jQuery, which will click `<td>` automatically:

```
$("#clickme").click
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve - but using HTML5's data-attributes for all your td attributes - its then an easy thing to have the click event tied to the td onclick and console.log the data-art_id of that td.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('td').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('data-art_id');
    console.log('art_id = ' + id);
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="60" height="60" cellpadding="0" 
cellspacing="0" border="0" style="float: left; margin: 1px" 
background="images/data/source_red.gif">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td data-act1="7" data-act3="8" data-store="true" data-art_id="4949" data-cnt="1" data-div_id="AA_4949" >td1</td>
        <td data-act1="8" data-act3="9" data-store="true" data-art_id="4950" data-cnt="1" data-div_id="AA_4950" > td2</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```